# Using "Microsoft Search" is not showing the RefinableString managed properties inside the "PnP search filter" web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp

I have created 2 SharePoint site columns of type managed metadata named "CustomDocumentType" & "CustomClient", as a result i got those 2 managed properties :-

[image]

[image]

and those 2 crawl properties:-

[image]

[image]

then i defined the 2 crawl properties inside the RefinaleString09 and RefinableString10, as follow:-

[image]

then i added "PnP Search Filter" web part from https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search which is linked to a "PnP Search Result" web part which uses "Microsoft Search", as follow:-

[image]

but the RefinaleString09 and RefinableString10 did not show inside the Filter fields inside the "PnP Search Filter" web part? any advice?

[image]

now i want to filter the documents using those 2 site columns? not sure how i need to configure the web parts?

Comment: Have you tried SharePoint Search instead?

Comment: @CallumCrowley Microsoft search aka Graph is more future proof

Comment: Agreed but I think the managed properties you're referring to are part of SharePoint Search, not Microsoft Search.

Comment: @Callum Crowley after waiting for 24 hours i were able to manually define the Refinable inside the filter web part.. they did not appear inside the filter dropdown but i were able to manually add them and they worked well, not sure if this is a hack or it should work in this way